Standhogg 2.0 vulnérability
I scanned my application with a tool that indicates it is vulnerable to Strandhogg 2.0.
[Critical] <Strandhogg> Standhogg 2.0:
           This application is vulnerable to the Standhogg 2.0 vulnerability. Please set activity launchModes to 'singleTask' or
           'singleInstance'. Please see https://promon.co/strandhogg-2-0/ for more details

It suggests me to set my launchModes to singleTask.
I would like to know if this is the solution to correct this vulnerability?
Knowing that my application can be used on a version of Android 8.0 at least.
NB: my launchMode is set singleTop actually.
[Critical] <Strandhogg> Standhogg 2.0:
           This application is vulnerable to the Standhogg 2.0 vulnerability. Please set activity launchModes to 'singleTask' or
           'singleInstance'. Please see https://promon.co/strandhogg-2-0/ for more details

